# Finding conditionally expected $y$ given a specific $x$ from a joint distribution function!

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I want to determine expected $y$, given $x=2$ given joint pdf shown below

> ### $$\frac{1}{2y} * e^{-\frac{y^2 + \frac{x}{2}}{y}}$$
>
> for $x,y \gt 0$ and $0$ otherwise

I believe this means I want to find $f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$, where I calculate $f_X(x)$ by integrating   the joint pdf from $0$ to $x$ with respect to $y$, but this I can't seem to compute(refer to prior edits).

Is there an alternative way that simplifies this? Thank you for your time!${}$${ }$

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ seem to be jointly continuous random variables, there is no need to do any computations to find the value of $P(Y = y\mid X = x)$. This probability is $0$ for all choices of real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @DilipSarwateb more specifically I am trying to find conditional expected y based on x=2, and I thought that I needed to calculate P(Y=y|X=x) to generate this

Comment: @DilipSarwate refer to completely rebuilt question  if it may please you sir.

Comment: First, $f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy$ and not 0 to x as you mentioned. Second, $E(Y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)$

Comment: As well, you should check to see if you have posted the correct integral...

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct joint pdf? Presumably
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi y}}e^{\Large-\frac{y^2+\frac{x}{2}}{y}}\ ?
$$

Comment: @undergrad I have realised my mistake, I want to find $f_{X\mid Y}(x|y)$ which is definitely a much easier problem, I got the answer four, but I am not entirely sure that is right.
(meaning I want expected X given Y=2)

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are trying to find E(X) or $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$. Can you modify your post to show your work. That way, more people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2y}e^{-(y+\frac{x}{2y})}dx = e^-y$
$f_Y(2)=e^{-2}$
$f_{X|Y}(x|2)= \frac{1}{4}e^{-(2+\frac{x}{4})}$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f_{X|Y}(x|2)}{f_Y(2)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{x}{4}} dx = 1$